# How can I access an iOS Mail password stored in Keychain?

Tags: iphone, icloud, mail.app, password, keychain

I upgraded my wife's iPhone to a newer model but she can't remember her Yahoo mail password which is stored in Keychain on her old phone.  She uses the standard iOS Mail app which successfully fetches mail from Yahoo on the old phone.

I've tried syncing the old phone's keychain to iCloud then syncing it back to the new phone using the same process, but with no success.  If I add the Yahoo account on the new phone I am always presented with a blank field for the password.

Should I reset the new phone completely and do a restore from iCloud?

Also I can't use Yahoo's 'forgot password' options on the web because the she also forgot the password to the rescue account.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: I didn't.  I did one restore of the phone and the password was not recovered.  I am not willing to jailbreak the phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you can sucessfully recieve email from your wifes old phone, maybe try restoring the password.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in Settings app > Safari > Passwords & Autofill > Saved Passwords. It *might* be there.

Alternatively, if you, or your wife, uses a Mac, you should be able use the **Keychain Access** app (In Applications > Utilities), if your wife's iCloud account is logged in on said Mac as well. Just search for "Yahoo" in the search box.

If it's not in any of those places, a full restore from iCloud might be your best option.

Comment: Yeah I tried the Saved Passwords in Safari's prefs but she never accessed Yahoo via the browser so it's not there.  Also tried the Keychain Access app, despite the iCloud sync there are no items corresponding to her Yahoo account.  So will try the full restore next - thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score -1):

There's a way using your jailbroken IPhone.
Just follow these instructions:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQFFedPArB8

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.